# Putting a UITabViewController inside UINavigationViewController with storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm using a storyboard to to lay out my app, and I would like to put a UINavigationController as my root and then UITabViewController as the root of that.  The main reasons I'm doing this are to save memory and to reduce the complexity of the controller tree.

So, is this an ok practice, and will this result in a more memory-efficient app than putting a separate nav controller in each tab?

Comment: what will you put in each tab?

Comment: The apple documentation says that a tab bar should be persistent to avoid confusing users. So if the tab bar disappears at any point, your app may be rejected from the app store.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to that documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

This question is regarding combining tab and navigation controllers while using a *storyboard*.  Here's a tutorial that that addresses this situation.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 1):

According to apple documentation. The tab bar controller should always be your root controller in this case. Here is a [tutorial](http://codenugget.org/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a) on how to put a navigation controller inside of a tab bar controller.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to that documentation?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Your UITabBarController should come first in the hierarchy, followed by your UINavigationController, and then your views. I would not worry terribly much about memory here: your app should already do the right things when iOS is low on memory (release what you can; rebuild it when requested by the user).